# How to compare ground truth and predicted images of deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have two lists which contain ground truth and predicted images. Both lists contains binary images. I need to obtain accuracy,f1-score,recall and precision reports between those two lists.

sklearn.metrics.classification_report can be  used to obtain the classification reports between prediction and truth values but it only accepts 1-d arrays.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

How to modify it to obtain the classification reports between two image lists which contain binary images? Or is there a better way to perform this? My code :

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

path_pred = "absolute_path/pred"
pred_list = next(os.walk(path_pred))[2]

true_list_new=[]
pred_list_new=[]

for img in pred_list:
    pred_img=cv2.imread("absolute_path/pred/%s" % img)
    true_img=cv2.imread("absolute_path/true/%s" % img)
    true_list_new.append(true_img)
    pred_list_new.append(pred_img)

print("Confusion Matrix: ", 
      confusion_matrix(true_list_new, pred_list_new)) 

print ("Accuracy : ", 
       accuracy_score(true_list_new,pred_list_new)*100) 

print("Report : ", 
      classification_report(true_list_new, pred_list_new))
```

p.s Solution

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

path_pred = "absolute_path/pred"
pred_list = next(os.walk(path_pred))[2]

true_list_new=[]
pred_list_new=[]

for img in pred_list:
    pred_img=cv2.imread("absolute_path/pred/%s" % img)
    true_img=cv2.imread("absolute_path/true/%s" % img)
    true_list_new.append(true_img)
    pred_list_new.append(pred_img)

true_list_new=np.array(true_list_new)
pred_list_new=np.array(pred_list_new)

true_list_new=true_list_new.flattern()
pred_list_new=pred_list_new.flattern()

print("Confusion Matrix: ", 
      confusion_matrix(true_list_new, pred_list_new)) 

print ("Accuracy : ", 
       accuracy_score(true_list_new,pred_list_new)*100) 

print("Report : ", 
      classification_report(true_list_new, pred_list_new))
```

Comment: what do you mean by accuracy, f1-score and precision/recall when comparing images? Those metrics are usually used when comparing scalar outputs.

Comment: are you predicting class of the images or the images? If you are predicting images, does that mean that in case of correct prediction you will have same images in pred and true?

Comment: @ Zaccharie Ramzi, @ SajanGohil My images are binary classified for water(255) and non water(0). What I'm currently doing is converting the ground truth image and the predicted image to numpy arrays. Next using the array.flattern() function to make them 1-D arrays and provide it as the input to the above mentioned functions. I need to know wether my method is accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to read the images and then **reshape them into a single row  vector**.
If you don't have to show them you can do **image.reshape(-1)**: with this line the image loaded by cv2 as a numpy array with multiple columns is then transformed into an numpy array with a single dimension.

Graphically:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],   ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Is this the same as converting the image into a numpy array and using the .flattern function?

Comment: Exactly. The images read with "imread" are returned as a numpy array, so you just have to flatten them.

Comment: If the answer is correct can you please mark it as correct? i need to gain a little bit of reputation =) thanks